# Google finance historical

Tags: python-2.7

So I was recently using the yahoo finance api for python in order to get stock data for a project. The .get_historical() function broke, which gives a list of closing prices, opening prices, etc for a particular stock over a duration of time (like closing prices for the last month). I started using google finance, and am wondering if there is anything like that, where I can get an up to date list that has closing prices for the last month. Is this possible? Here is what I have tried for google finance:

```
from googlefinance import getQuotes
import json
print json.dumps(getQuotes('AAPL'), indent=2)
[
  {
    "Index": "NASDAQ",
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "129.09",
    "LastTradeDateTime": "2015-03-02T16:04:29Z",
    "LastTradePrice": "129.09",
    "Yield": "1.46",
    "LastTradeTime": "4:04PM EST",
    "LastTradeDateTimeLong": "Mar 2, 4:04PM EST",
    "Dividend": "0.47",
    "StockSymbol": "AAPL",
    "ID": "22144"
  }
]
```

however this doesn't seem to give historical data of any kind

Comment: Seems like `googlefinance` & `yahoo_finance` APIs have gone defunct, maybe look into the [Quandl Python Package](https://www.quandl.com/tools/python) -- I tried it with your query and got back a lot of data, not sure which data is the 'closing prices' but there is something they call 'End of Day' in the API (https://www.quandl.com/data/EOD/AAPL-Apple-Inc-AAPL-Stock-Prices-Dividends-and-Splits), `quandl.get("EOD/AAPL", myauthtoken)` gives `Adj_Open    Adj_High     Adj_Low   Adj_Close   Adj_Volume` for every date, back to `1980-12-12`

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas_data reader like:

```
    import pandas_datareader.data as wb
    web_df = wb.DataReader(symbols, 'google', date_start, date_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution. Hope it is useful to someone.

```
import pandas
import requests
import io

stock = 'GOOG'
startdate = 'Jul 08, 2017'
enddate = 'Aug 08, 2017'

rooturl = 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q='
query = stock + '&startdate=' + startdate +'&enddate=' + enddate + '&output=csv'

url = rooturl + query
response = requests.get(url)
df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.content.decode('utf-8')))

print(df)
```

The idea is that you can get a response as a csv file by adding the output=csv

You end up with an url like this:

http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=GOOG&startdate=Jul%2008%2C%202017&enddate=Aug%2008%2C%202017&output=csv